# Installing Google Account on i9500 on leaked 5.0.1

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-4, 5.0-lollipop

I recently installed the leaked lollipop 5.0.1 ROM for the s4 i9500. I can see that it does not come with the google package of google play, google search and also one cannot add a google account in the accounts. 
I downloaded the apk but that is not running and not even an error is displayed when i click on it. 
Is there a way to get google play without rooting? and even add a google account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below procedure:

1. Download the ROM
2. Download [GApps](https://s.basketbuild.com/filedl/gapps?dl=gapps-lp-20141109-signed.zip) package for Lollipop
3. Download [SuperSU](http://download.chainfire.eu/641/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.40.zip?retrieve_file=1)
4. Put the zip files on your SDCard
5. Reboot in Recovery
6. Wipe Data / Factory Reset
7. Select "Install zip from SDCard"
8. Choose ROM zip file
9. Choose GApps zip file
10. Choose SuperSU zip file
11. Reboot system

You need customized google apps package.

Courtesy:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4/i9505-orig-develop/rom-cyanogenmod-12-t2943934